# Cast int to enum from sql query C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How to return `IEnumerable` with `NewUnitPhaseStatus` as an enum?

In SQL the value "NewUnitPhaseStatus" is stored as an int. If I just return the query, then when I try to extract the value it just says that the DBcontext has been disposed. But If I try to convert the query result into a list, then it says that int cannot be converted to type NewUnitPhaseStatus(the enum type).

```
public IEnumerable<UnitPhaseLog> GetAllForUnitPhase(long unitPhaseId)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext(_connStringKey))
    {
         var querys = from s in db.UnitPhaseLogs 
                      where s.UnitPhaseId == unitPhaseId 
                      select s;

          return querys;
     }
}
```

If one uses a foreach statement to convert each row into an enum, they get an error because var query is of class UnitPhaseLog with NewUnitPhaseStatus equal to enum.

Error message:

If one tries to convert the results to a list.

> The 'NewUnitPhaseStatus' property on 'UnitPhaseLog' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Core.UnitPhaseStatus'.

If one tries to just return the query results themselves:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Code:

```
public enum UnitPhaseStatus
{
    [Display(Name = "No Status")]
    NoStatus,
    [Display(Name = "Not Ready")]
    NotReady,
    [Display(Name = "Materials Needed")]
    MaterialsNeeded,
    [Display(Name = "Ready For Work")]
    ReadyForWork,
    [Display(Name = "Work In Progress")]
    WorkInProgress,
    [Display(Name = "Ready")]
    ReadyForQc,
    [Display(Name = "Approved")]
    Approved,
    [Display(Name = "Rejected")]
    Rejected,
}
```

Comment: You talking about this line? `UnitPhaseStatus UnitPhaseStatus = query.NewUnitPhaseStatus;`

Comment: So in SQL the value is stored as an int. I am trying to return it as enum of class UnitPhaseStatus

Comment: Please show the code that defined UnitPhaseStatus .
Your enum values should match the SQL definition.

Comment: Look at @DigiFriend answer. In your enum definition, you have to add = VALUE:
NoStatus = 0,
NotReady = 1,
MaterialsNeeded = 2

WHERE 0,1 and 2 will match the value in your SQL column.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply return `querys`?

Comment: Digi, thats how the code was previously set up. But i dont understand how the bigint becomes an enum

Comment: You ORM (Entity Framework?) does the conversion for you.

Comment: How can you just return querys? Wouldnt the DBcontext get disposed because it is an IEnumerable? Dont you need to convert it to a list?

Comment: Looks like it may just be a length problem.  Try "public enum UnitPhaseStatus : long" instead of "public enum UnitPhaseStatus".  If that fixes it, it means you're schema and enum didn't match int sizes (32 vs 64-bit).

Comment: You talk about `NewUnitPhaseStatus` but your code does not contain any mention of `NewUnitPhaseStatus`. ??

Comment: You are also throwing around various error messages you receive with what you try to do, but in an unspecific, unreproducable way. You describe what you try to do, but without code, so it is unclear where and how you do it. And as you receive errors obviously something about your assumptions is wrong/incomplete. You should provide code examples of what you tried so the issue can be pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the return value from the database to the enum type.

```
unit.NewUnitPhaseStatus = (UnitPhaseStatus)UnitPhaseStatus;
```

Though, you can do this directly, instead of having to go through an extra local variable.

So, instead of:

```
UnitPhaseStatus UnitPhaseStatus = query.NewUnitPhaseStatus;
unit.NewUnitPhaseStatus = UnitPhaseStatus;
```

You can use:

```
unit.NewUnitPhaseStatus = (UnitPhaseStatus)query.NewUnitPhaseStatus;
```

Comment: The code breaks at the foreach statement because var query is of type NewUnitPhaseStatus, which is an enum

Comment: I don't think you follow. OK. What type is `UnitPhaseLog.NewUnitPhaseStatus`? What type is `query.NewUnitPhaseStatus` (not the name - the type)? The types need to match. If they do not, you need to cast.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you're using Entity Framework, so if you're not doing so feel free to ignore.

Rather than worry about casting an Int to an enum, or an enum to an Int, a better solution might be to change the Entity to bind that column directly to the enum and letting the framework do the conversion for you.

Comment: But then how do you query the results?

Comment: If you get around the conversion errors you're getting, you should be able to get the result as a list.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to mess with that `foreach` loop - your `querys` is already of the right type, so if it isn't `null`, just return that.

```
public IEnumerable<UnitPhaseLog> GetAllForUnitPhase(long unitPhaseId)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext(_connStringKey))
    {
        var querys = from s in db.UnitPhaseLogs where s.UnitPhaseId == unitPhaseId select s;

        List<UnitPhaseLog> UnitPhaseLogList = new List<UnitPhaseLog>();
        if (null == querys) return UnitPhaseLogList;

        return querys;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'NewUnitPhaseStatus' property on 'UnitPhaseLog' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Core.UnitPhaseStatus'.

Comment: This suggests that your `UnitPhaseLog.NewUnitPhaseStatus` is a `long`, when it really should be a `Core.UnitPhaseStatus`. This is probably where all your problems are coming from.

Comment: It is a UnitPhaseStatus. I noticed that if I dont turn the IEnumerable into a list before retrieving data, then it says the data has been disposed.

Comment: From my experience, even if I just return queries (like how it is in your answer above) the data isnt accessable because it is disposed.

Comment: I showed the class of the UnitPhaseLog.NewUnitPhaseStatus in the question